# ruby can't find readline on OS X 10.6

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm running ruby 1.9.2 on OS X 10.6, and mostly things are working fine.  But readline doesn't seem to be working, either in IRB or in the rails console.  A few different posts suggested building readline as an extension, like this

```
cd <ruby-source-dir>/ext/readline
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

So I did that, and here's what I get:

```
checking for tgetnum() in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking for readline() in -lreadline... no
checking for readline() in -ledit... no
checking for editline/readline.h... yes
checking for readline() in -ledit... no
```

and then

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'
```

This makes me think it's not finding my readline install.  Any ideas on how to get it to find readline?

Comment: I'd just install Ruby through `rvm` and forget about system Ruby, but if you don't want that, maybe have a look at the following link: http://www.jorgebernal.info/development/fixing-snow-leopard-ruby-readline

Comment: I just installed rvm and got Ruby running on that, but interestingly enough it had the same problem with trying to find readline.  I had to run rvm install 1.8.7 --with-readline-dir=/usr/local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-compiled readline and then tried the steps above again and everything worked fine.  I think this *may* be because I had originally compiled readline for osx 10.5, when ruby was still 32 bits.